# Facing issue after Upgrade to Angular 16, Angular Material 16, and MDC:Migrate

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am facing following issue after upgraded to angular 16 from Angular 16

```
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Undefined function.
92 │   @return typography.resolve-theme($theme, $resolver, 'supporting-text');
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

@material\tooltip\_plain-tooltip-theme.scss 92:11                         -resolve-theme-typography()
  @material\tooltip\_plain-tooltip-theme.scss 86:5                          -resolve-theme()
  @material\tooltip\_plain-tooltip-theme.scss 49:11                         theme()
  node_modules\@angular\material\tooltip\_tooltip-theme.scss 23:5           typography()
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\typography\_all-typography.scss 74:3  all-component-typographies()
  src\assets\themes\theme_002.scss 15:1                                     @import
  src\app.theme.scss 23:9                                                root stylesheet

./src/app.theme.scss?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Undefined function.
92 │   @return typography.resolve-theme($theme, $resolver, 'supporting-text');
   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  @material\tooltip\_plain-tooltip-theme.scss 92:11                         -resolve-theme-typography()
  @material\tooltip\_plain-tooltip-theme.scss 86:5                          -resolve-theme()
  @material\tooltip\_plain-tooltip-theme.scss 49:11                         theme()
  node_modules\@angular\material\tooltip\_tooltip-theme.scss 23:5           typography()
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\typography\_all-typography.scss 74:3  all-component-typographies()
  src\app.theme.scss 16:1
```

I upgraded code from Angular v15 to v16, then I upgrade @angular/material@16 and after that when I try to mdc:Migrate for Angular Select Because it Legacy was conflicted with ngx-mat-select-search